# problem in starting emulator in win2000

Tags: android

I am android beginner and while running emulator in win2000 i am getting bellow error

***the procedure entry point addressinfo could not be located in the dynamic link library WS2_32.DLL***

Thanks

Comment: As you can see here: http://developer.android.com/sdk/requirements.html the SDK supports Win XP and Vista. It works ok on 7 too, but looks like not on older systems.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use Windows 2000.